# phpDocumentor Not working

Tags: php, phpdoc

Im trying to get started using phpDocumentor. My problem is its only generating a img,css,js folders and a structure.xml file.

I have currently created a folder in c:/xampp/htdocs called phpTest with 1 file index.php with  a class and some docBlox comments

I have installed phpDocumentor using pear and the command prompt

So im currently running cmd

typing cd c:/xampp/htdocs/phptest

phpDocs -d c:/xampp/htdocs/phptest -t c:/xampp/htdocs/phptest/docs

and the only output in the docs folder is the 3 folders and structure.xml file. Should there be an index.hmtl file with all the documentation available for me to see? How do i get it to show up? Thanks
This is my test index.php File im trying to document with phpDocumentor.

```
    <?php
/**
* File level docBlock
*@package Command
*/

/**
*This is the command class it is incharge
*Only has execute method
*@package Command
*@author Michael Booth
*@copyright 2012 bla bla
*/
abstract class Command{
/**
*keeps keys values
*@var array
*/
public var  $arrayvar = array();

/**
*executes method
*@param $int contains contextual data
*@return bool
*/
    abstract function execute($integer);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your docblocks begin with slash-asterisk-asterisk, as opposed to the PHP regular comment syntax of slash-asterisk.  Also, be sure you have at least some tags in the docblock (e.g. @package MyPackage).  phpDoc won't see the regular comment blocks, so that may itself be the reason nothing is being generated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because PHP will report a syntax error in your file. The line

```
public var  $arrayvar = array();
```

should be either

```
public $arrayvar = array();
```

or

```
var $arrayvar = array();
```